Grammatically speaking, is using one's own name really "speaking in the third person"?
I keep seeing this myth perpetuated in western media, that when an Asian uses their own name, they're somehow "speaking in the third person". This article on TV Tropes, the go-to source of unverifiable nonsense, makes bold claims about speaking in the third person in "Japanese media" in particular. Manga/anime translators seem to struggle at grasping this, results in awkward translations that portray sensible characters as babbling infants.
As far as I can tell, speaking the third person, or illeism, is very Eurocentric, because it requires "person" as a grammatical concept to exist, something that Japanese and most Asian languages do not have. Person in Japanese is purely semantic, not grammatical, for the simple fact that there's no distinct verb form for any single person, nor is there grammatical agreement between "third person" nouns and pronouns and adjectives. Illeism, on the other hand, entails the hypothetical speaker to make use of third person pronouns, third person verb forms, and grammatical agreement especially in terms of gender. The only thing that Japanese people in particular and other Asians in general do that's close to this is using their own name. But that's only replacing the pronoun "I/me" with their name, it's very much first person, not third. In fact, using names as pronoun stand-ins is very flexible, and it can encompass all three "persons":

When you're talking to someone you're close to, you can use your name and theirs instead of "I/me" and "you".
When you're talking about somebody else affectionately, it's perfectly sensible to use their name instead of "she/her/he/him/they/them."

Personally, as someone who speaks a language where using names as pronoun substitutions is pervasive, I've sort of made up my mind about this. The only reason I'm asking this question is to check to consensus among Japanese grammarians, as to whether this usage of one's own name can be characterized as "speaking in the third person" at all, and whether "person" even means anything in Japanese grammar. Academic sources would be appreciated.

This is a matter of culture and perception rather than fact; grammar (as a general, language-agnostic concept) isn't objective in the way that it would need to be to make this question make sense. The closest I can come up with that would work is "does traditional Japanese grammatical analysis include a concept of 'grammatical person'?", but I think that might be too vague.

@KarlKnechtel Now that you mention "traditional Japanese grammatical analysis", I remember that pronouns aren't traditionally really considered as a distinct grammatical class, but merely a subclass of nouns. In fact, all modern pronouns, except 我, behave exactly like nouns, and some like 私, あなた, 君, were originally nouns. Compared to English, where the possessive form of she is her, not she's, meaning English pronouns behave differently from nouns to some extent. Person is strongly associated with pronouns, so if pronouns don't exist, person shouldn't either.

In the first place, when people say 'speaking in third person' in English, they're talking semantically and not grammatically. No one speaking in English would regard 'I wants bacon for dinner' as 'talking in third person'.

illeism, is very Eurocentric, because it requires "person" as a grammatical concept to exist Why? According to that Wikipedia article, it's merely a writing style or rhetorical device, and it has nothing to do with grammar. Or are you suggesting the Japanese language cannot distinguish 1st person view and 3rd person view because it lacks "-s"?

@naruto Of course it's "stylistic" in the sense that no normal person would speak like that if they weren't trying convey some kind of effect. The question is how does "third person" manifest itself, if it weren't through grammatical markers? When you use your own name, is it any similar to using the pronoun "he/him" (hence, "illeism"), in the "rhetorical" sense that you're really viewing yourself as a detached third party? The way I'd personally view myself if I used my own name is that my own name represents me, in the first person.

@Angelos Nobody would say "I wants bacon for dinner" in the first place. It's not any kind of first, second or third person. Using broken/nonstandard grammar is just that, broken/nonstandard grammar. This is a complete non-sequitur. When people purposely engage with speech, even for semantic effect as you claim, what they do is to make use of the semantics, lexicon and grammar they know for a fact is acceptable, only in an unusual way. What they do not do is to speak like Tarzan or some kind of prehistoric cartoon caveman.

@Angelos Third-person characters still very much obey regular grammar. When Donnie speaks in the third person, for example as in, "You can't trick ol' Donnie, he's not that dumb, he knows what's up'", he still observes regular grammar with "he" and "'s" and "knows". Your nonsensical hypothetical is analogous to "I's not that dumb, I knows what's up".

As you said, just using one's own name instead of わたし or such does not mean she is speaking from a third person view. In Japanese, 名前呼び is merely one of the many ways of referring to the speaker themselves, and such names should simply be converted to "I/me" when translated into English. In my opinion, you can safely ignore arguments that try to connect such a simple fact mainly observed in child language to complicated topics like perspective shifting.
However, I strongly disagree that illeism is an Eurocentric concept. You don't need a grammatical third person to achieve illeism. The existence of 名前呼び does not mean Japanese cannot distinguish 1st and 3rd person views, nor does it mean illeism is impossible in Japanese. Here are trivial examples:

エリカも食べたい！
I wanna eat it, too!
エリカも食べたがってる！
Erika wants to eat it, too!
エリカが教えてあげるよ。
I will teach it (to you)!
エリカが教えてくれるよ。
Erika will teach it (to you)!

Various other expressions that do not exist in English, including (て)くる, (て)いく and keigo, can suggest the position of the mental "camera". According to that Wikipedia article, illeism is nothing more than a stylistic device occasionally used with some intentions, and it has little to do with the grammar of a certain language. Needless to say, people who always talk about themselves from a third-person perspective exist only in fiction, both in English and in Japanese.

"does not mean Japanese cannot distinguish 1st and 3rd person views" I don't know how you can infer this from my question. I do not doubt Japanese people aren't mentally capable of doing this. The very fact that Japanese writers are still aware of such constructed semantic pronouns as 彼 and 彼女 means that they are capable. The fact of the matter is that they don't have their characters refer to themselves as 彼 and 彼女, the way English writers would do to portray "third-person characters".

By "Eurocentric", I was clear what I meant was the use of third-person pronouns ("she/her/he/him", "il/lui/elle"), third-person verb froms ("works", "travaille", "travaillait") and grammatical agreement ("la belle Jolie" instead of "la belle moi" for example). These features are the only way for European languages to convey third-person. You can claim you're viewing yourself in the third person, but how do you show that, without grammar?

What you're doing with your constructed examples with てくれる is similar in that regard, that you must show your "external camera" somehow through the means of grammar, which I concede is not Euroncentric, since I wasn't aware that you can use てくれる and がってる this way.

@Vun-HughVaw These features are the only way for European languages to convey third-person. Why? How should I read the article you linked to conclude that illeism is only possible in English because it has the rule of adding "s" conditionally to verbs? Or do you say illeism in English is impossible in past tense because verbs look the same in past tense regardless of whether the subject is I or he? Basically everyone's pointing out the same thing; expressing viewpoints has little to do with such small grammar rules.

"How should I read the article you linked to conclude that illeism is only possible in English because it has the rule of adding "s" conditionally to verbs" It's so weird that you keep insisting on this fallacious notion. How do you keep getting this impression after I've explained it multiple times? I've already cited pronoun choices and grammatical agreement, something that's not unique to English. English is one example among many, and it's convenient to cite it here given how I'm speaking English to you. English historically lost of inflections and grammatical agreement.

Just to make it clear one last time, "illeism", as its name suggests, involves the use of the third-person as a grammatical concept, to show that you're indeed, engaging in this type of speaking. Using third person pronouns ("ille" in Latin), third person verb forms, third person grammatical agreement. Don't limit yourself to English, you can find examples in French or German. If you think of anything else these European languages are capable of, feel free to ask. For Japanese, you've demonstrated that there are other ways, which I've conceded as possible.

Now if you must insist English as an example, here are two ways English writers employ to convey third-person speaking: noun + third-person verb form ("Donnie's smarter than you think", "this man's smarter than you think", "your dad's smarter than you think"), third-person pronoun + third-person verb form ("he's smarter than you think"). Without a subject, it's impossible to tell if there's third-person speaking going on in the past tense for most verbs, as in "worked Sundays" (I worked?, you worked? Donnie worked?)

In languages where third person verb forms are more distinct like French, German and Spanish, it's easier to tell. For pro-drop languages like Spanish, pronouns are mostly redundant because you can tell by the distinct third-person verb forms alone. Clearly the -s in the present form in English isn't the only way to mark third person.

As for the Wikipedia article, read the examples and analyze them. In what ways could you infer that these examples constitute "illeism"? Is it only because the Wikipedia article listed them there and insist that they do? Or is it because the grammatical clues that occur in those examples? Apply the same analysis to your own constructed examples. How can you tell that エリカも食べたい is first person but エリカも食べたがってる is third person? Is it because you merely will the third person into existence, or is it because of the grammatical clues, like がってる and くてる?

@Vun-HughVaw Let's not mix "α: speaking from a third-person view for certain effect" and "β: grammatical third person". I believe the Wikipedia article you linked refers to α. And in this question, you're asking 1) whether just using one's own name instead of 私 counts as an example of α, and 2) whether α is possible in a language like Japanese. Am I right? My answer is "No" for 1. For 2, my answer is "Yes, of course; a technique like α has nothing to do with small grammar rules such as subject-verb agreement". Like "He (referring to self) will not give up" in English, one may say "この男は諦めません".

It is entirely possible to achieve effects described in the Wikipedia article in Japanese, and it seems completely unrelated to the grammar of Indo-European languages to me. Even if English had no rule involving 's', it wouldn’t matter. Even if Japanese had a rule to change verb conjugations based on the type of the subject, it wouldn't matter. That's β, not α.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
